# Setting linux time properly (UTC)

Tags: linux

I have problems with the time settings on my linux server. The timezone is set to UTC, the locale settings are the following: (locale -a)

C
C.UTF-8
en_GB.utf8
POSIX

date command gives me
Wed Jul 26 09:39:42 UTC 2017
but the correct time is 10:39

On my desktop I have the same locale settings and utc timezone and it gives me the correct time.
Could someone explain what's wrong with the server and what should be changed, please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps your desktop environment has `TZ` set to (e.g.) `Europe/London` - check whether it's showing `BST` in place of `UTC`.

Comment: cat /etc/timezone shows
Etc/UTC on both machines

Comment: You need to softlink `/etc/localtime` to the correct *zoneinfo* file in `/usr/share/zoneinfo/` like `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/London` (or whatever your zone actually is)

Comment: What's relevant es the *environment* setting of `TZ` - `/etc/timezone` is just the fallback/default value.

Comment: I'm not sure we are communicating -- but that is where the environment setting is derived from.